# Best practices for Plone control panels

Tags: registry, plone, uninstallation

I'm working on a [package](http://github.com/collective/collective.nitf) that includes a control panel created using plone.app.registry. I followed [Timo's tutorial](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/how-to-create-a-plone-control-panel-with-plone.app.registry) but, when trying to add an additional record to it, I'm facing the infamous **KeyError: a field for which there is no record**.

So I have a couple of questions about best practices:

My first question is: a package must remove it's registry at uninstall time?

I used this in registry.xml of my package:

```
<registry>
  <records interface="collective.nitf.controlpanel.INITFSettings" />
</registry>
```

and this on metadata.xml:

```
<metadata>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>profile-plone.app.registry:default</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</metadata>
```

But adding a delete="true" on the uninstall profile seems not to be working. I tried also by listing all records by name with no luck, unless I run the step manually at ZMI.

So, my second question is: how do I remove control panel records at uninstall time gracefully?

To test if a record is on the registry I do something like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.portal = self.layer['portal']
    setRoles(self.portal, TEST_USER_ID, ['Manager'])
    # Set up the NITF settings registry
    self.registry = Registry()
    self.registry.registerInterface(INITFSettings)

def test_record_sections(self):
    # Test that the sections record is in the control panel
    record_sections = self.registry.records[
        'collective.nitf.controlpanel.INITFSettings.sections']
    self.failUnless('sections' in INITFSettings)
    self.assertEquals(record_sections.value, set([]))
```

A third question could be how to test if a record was removed at unisntall time.

Any other recommendation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: I have not used plone.app.registry myself directly in a package yet.

> My first question is: a package must remove it's registry at uninstall
>   time?

Yes.  It at least seems reasonable to expect this from authors of community packages.  I would hope that plone.app.registry does not trip over missing stuff from old removed packages, like it seems to be doing here, but that may be tricky.

> So, my second question is: how do I remove control panel records at uninstall time gracefully?

In most GenericSetup files `remove="True"` works. Not sure about this specific case.

Comment: [Deleting records](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.registry#deleting-records) on plone.app.registry is a little bit different and is not working for me; you have to do something like this:

    <record name="my.package.myRecord" delete="true" />

I was trying adding a prefix attribute to the [creation based on an interface](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.registry#creating-records-based-on-an-interface), but it's not pretty clear in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
My first question is: a package must remove it's registry at uninstall time?
```

I'm not part of remove things on uninstall time because some time you don't want to lose your configuration at re install... providing a way to cleanup the registry should be better for administrator of the site. Do test on a test instance where you don't care to lost your data.

The second question is already answered by maurits, so you should care about typo:

delete="true" != "remove="True"

Comment: This is why after a product with a GenericSetup profile has been installed the Add/Remove products panel only offers the option to uninstall it and not anymore (Plone 3.3 and upwards) to reinstall it. It only offers to apply the upgrade steps if any have been registered.  Reinstalling via the portal_quickinstaller is still possible for power users, but they should know the possible snags, like you mention above.

Comment: delete="true" works in plone.app.registry but only if I run the step manually at portal_setup; remove="true" is not documented.

Comment: @hvelarde documentation: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/genericsetup/creating-an-uninstall-profile and  http://packages.python.org/Products.GenericSetup/profiles.html#update-directives

Comment: @maurits I guess this is also to force developers to create upgrade steps, at least this is why I have started to write them on my own add-ons :)